# Regular Expression always returns false

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have a problem to get a regular expression to get work.

I use an XMLRPC Library to get information from an wiki.

so far so good.

After retrieving the data into a String Variable I would like to search through with a regular expression but the matcher will always return "false".

But if I asking the String ....contains("xyz"); the Answer is true.

The String looks something like this:

> ====== Datensicherheit ====== ''Kriterium von Sicherheit'' Typ: technisch Definition: \ //Allgemein.........

```
String regex = "Definition";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read the Javadocs for `matches()`?

Comment: how about `text.contains("Definition")`?

Comment: Why is this tagged with Python?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with your regex expression. If you are wanting to know if the string contains "Definition", your regex needs to be:

```
String regex = ".*Definition.*";
```

Comment: This would still use the matches() function. John's answer of using find() is probably more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `matches()` returns true if, and only if, the entire region sequence matches this matcher's pattern. see the java doc @ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()

So, it will only be true if the entire "text" region matches "Definition", which is unlikely :).

Try `find()` instead which is true if, and only if, a subsequence of the input sequence starting at the given index matches this matcher's pattern.

Comment: It's fine :) we've all gotten tunnel vision when debugging and missed a doc at times.